# It is possible to automatically break upon entering code from specific file/class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have a badly written file in c++ that I need to debug in Visual Studio. I would want break execution of my program always when code from that file is called. Entire file (by that i mean .cpp + .h files) is a huge class and helping enums that are used by that class.
Is there a way to set debbuger to break when program is reaching code from that file or class other than manually setting breakpoints on each method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio allows [class breakpoints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/09/10/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger.aspx)

[image]

This will allow you to break in the executable lines of your class as soon as its code is called. Constructors included.

Comment: Visual Studio's depth surprises me on a regular basis.

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Thanks.